# Change mimetype for VSC Jupyter Notebook ouput

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'd like to change the output format in VSC from `html` to `plain`. I notice I can do this for individual cell as below, but I wonder if I can change the settings.json for the entire file. I'm using Jupyter Notebook.

[image]

Comment: Same question here. Did you figure it out by any chance?

Comment: Hi @shkelda, unfortunately no

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the vscode notebook console
click ["customize notebook layout"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uumPO.png)

click ["editting settings.json"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufrH6.png)

you should see something like this:

```
{"workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
"editor.fontSize": 16,
"notebook.lineNumbers": "on",
"notebook.output.textLineLimit": 50,
"notebook.editorOptionsCustomizations": null,
"terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false,
"notebook.displayOrder": ["image/png", "text/plain"]}
```

Update the last line with your prefered order of output format.