# VSCode Jupyter Notebook, how to change presentation/add mimetypes (changing the notebook output renderer options)

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, mime-types

I've referenced this question: [Change mimetype for VSC Jupyter Notebook ouput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68555264/change-mimetype-for-vsc-jupyter-notebook-ouput)

And thoroughly googled, but I still can't seem to change the mime type of my Jupyter Notebook.  I have 2 .jpnyb files opened, one has the option of mimetypes of text/html, text/plain and the other gives a weird one of application/vnd.somemorewords

Here is a picture of what the difference between the two look like within the command palette when attempting to change the presentation. First file: https://ibb.co/yBkmVdz  Second file: https://ibb.co/vhcz866

Where is the first file grabbing the mimetypes from?  I can't find any information on a location of a file (settings.json has been edited) that just sets the standard across the board for the entire VS Code app.  Please help if you can!

I've done a search of package.json files on my computer and looked at over 50+ files for some sort of information of the notebook display order and renderer.

I also tried changing the User settings for the work space referencing the question that I linked above.