# How to change VSCode output's presentation?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

[image]

I do not like the presentation format that separates my dataframe into two rows. This problem also appears in my debug console, but it was not like that some days ago. I clicked the "..." on the left of the output and select "change presentation", but VSCode only gives me one option ( shown in the last image). It had about three options before, but they are not here anymore.

I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70302982/12976646) to change my settings.json, but it makes no difference. What can I do to have all the columns display in one row?

[image]

My settings.json is

```
{
"workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
"[python]": {
    "editor.formatOnType": true
},
"git.autofetch": true,
"notebook.displayOrder": [
    "image/png",
    "text/plain"
 ]
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58665752/53341

Comment: @MatBailie `print(dataframe.to_string())` might be better.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75797892/12715723) should be better too. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using:

```py
print(df.head())
```

just use:

```py
df.head()
```

It will print your csv in a prettier format without dataframe separation, but make sure that variable is at the end of the code.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('homelessness.csv')
df['x'] = '541651348'
df.head()
```

If the dataframe is in collapse mode, you can expand/show all columns with this `pandas` setup:

```py
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
```

Answer (score 0):

An existing problem on [github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1501#issuecomment-647814842). The output will be unreadable if working with wide dataframes.

One feasible approach is to use **the data viewer** by clicking **Variables**.

[image]

[image]

Then you could get the table as an alternative. I've submitted your original problem as a feature request to developer [on github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/13125).

Comment: Thank you for submitting my question to the developer. I appreciate it.